# I have this error but how can i go about it type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to create the endpoint but it was giving me the above error in console
My machine_request model part of the code snippet

```
  MachineRequestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
this.id = json['id'];
this.location = json['location'];
this.is_accepted = json['is_accepted'];
this.is_complete = json['is_complete'];
this.machine = json['machine'];
this.customer = json['customer'];
this.machine_owner = json['machine_owner'];
this.from_date = json['from_date'];
this.to_date = json['to_date'];
this.total_price = double.parse(json['total_price']);}
```

My provider for the machine request provider

```
 Future<List<MachineRequestModel>> getMachineRequests() async {
_isLoading = true;
notifyListeners();
ApiResponse apiResponse = await machineRequestsRepo.getMachineRequests();
_isLoading = false;
if (apiResponse.response != null &&
    apiResponse.response.statusCode == 200) {
  Map _map = apiResponse.response.data;
  machineRequests = _map['requests']
      .map<MachineRequestModel>(
          (value) => MachineRequestModel.fromJson(value))
      .toList();
  notifyListeners();
  return machineRequests;
} else {
  String errorMessage;
  if (apiResponse.error is String) {
    print(apiResponse.error.toString());
    errorMessage = apiResponse.error.toString();
  } else {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = apiResponse.error;
    print(errorResponse.errors[0].message);
    errorMessage = errorResponse.errors[0].message;
  }
  machineRequestError = errorMessage;
  notifyListeners();
}}
```

In case someone has an idea I can fix this I will really appreciete it.

Comment: Can you print `apiResponse` and show the result?

Comment: It returns a list of requests

Comment: I wanted to see the structure of `apiResponse` with the  _print_ but nevermind. Are you sure `errorResponse.errors` is a collection ?

Comment: You should let us see a response sample, and also, where is the stacktrace? How can we know in which line the error is?

Comment: Post a sample of the response, stacktrace & your MachineRequestModel to be able to help